# I have problems opening my app on Android after using Kivy/Buildozer

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I'm working on an android app project that will ultimately use OpenCV (didn't reach that part yet). I only finished the functionality part of the project but it keeps crashing as soon as it opens on my Android phone (Haewai P20). Before that, I did the famous "Hello world" test and the app showing these 2 words opened fine. I read a lot of forums but can't find any solutions.

I'm working on PyCharm with python 3.7 and the app works fine when I'm opening it on Windows. Then I'm using buildozer on Ubuntu 18.04 on VirtualBox 6.0.6.

I didn't wanted to copy paste all my logcat, buildozer.spec and log files so you can have a look at them here:

buildozer.spec:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DHClpIxnOGKtev2nRefau85v12IzjJWm

log.txt created with buildozer:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wlQmQjWH27WRef--tLPtN9FGWTE13lLL

logcat.txt (only the part where I installed it and opened it):

https://drive.google.com/open?id=17ovrucpeKWpJh6MBw7e5ZUbxO3S1DSnS

I'm not sure exactly what to look at. I have a feeling that there's an incompatibility between Python versions (buildozer uses 2.7) but I'm not sure how to deal with that. If it's really the problem.

Please let me know if you have problems opening these files and if you need anything else.

Thank you very much in advance for your help and time.

Comment: "buildozer.spec" requirements can not auto install dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How to search for error in logcat?

Either search for "*I python*" using an editor or `buildozer android debug deploy run > grep "I python"`

## Logcat3.txt - Error

```
08-11 17:05:10.323  7746  7801 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.digitable/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_19-08-11_0.txt
08-11 17:05:10.323  7746  7801 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.0
08-11 17:05:10.323  7746  7801 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.digitable/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyo"
08-11 17:05:10.323  7746  7801 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.15 (default, Aug 11 2019, 16:47:41)
08-11 17:05:10.323  7746  7801 I python  : [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Android (4691093 based on r316199) Clang 6.0.2 (https://a
08-11 17:05:10.323  7746  7801 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
08-11 17:05:10.324  7746  7801 I python  : [WARNING] [Deprecated  ] Python 2 Kivy support has been deprecated. The Kivy release after 1.11.0 will not support Python 2 anymore
08-11 17:05:10.781  7746  7801 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
08-11 17:05:11.027  7746  7801 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
08-11 17:05:11.063  7746  7801 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
08-11 17:05:11.217  7746  7801 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
08-11 17:05:11.218  7746  7801 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
08-11 17:05:11.219  7746  7801 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 3.2 v1.r14p0-00cet0.0416641283c5d6e2d53c163d0ca99357>
08-11 17:05:11.219  7746  7801 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <ARM>
08-11 17:05:11.219  7746  7801 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Mali-G72>
08-11 17:05:11.219  7746  7801 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
08-11 17:05:11.220  7746  7801 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
08-11 17:05:11.220  7746  7801 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
08-11 17:05:11.268  7746  7801 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
08-11 17:05:11.269  7746  7801 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
08-11 17:05:11.272  7746  7801 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
08-11 17:05:11.272  7746  7801 I python  :    File "/home/laurent/Downloads/Files4apk/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 15, in <module>
08-11 17:05:11.273  7746  7801 I python  :    File "/home/laurent/Downloads/Files4apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/digitable/pandas/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
08-11 17:05:11.273  7746  7801 I python  :  ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy', 'pytz', 'dateutil']
08-11 17:05:11.273  7746  7801 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

### Problem

Your buildozer.spec is missing dependencies ['numpy', 'pytz', 'dateutil']

### Solution

Add dependencies ['numpy', 'pytz', 'dateutil'] to requirements in buildozer.spec

```
requirements = python2,kivy,pandas,numpy,pytz,dateutil
```

## Logcat1.txt - Error

```
08-11 09:19:50.492 10715 10755 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.digitable/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_19-08-11_1.txt 
08-11 09:19:50.492 10715 10755 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.0 
08-11 09:19:50.493 10715 10755 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy     ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.digitable/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyo" 
08-11 09:19:50.493 10715 10755 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.15 (default, Aug 10 2019, 22:32:55)  
08-11 09:19:50.493 10715 10755 I python  : [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Android (4691093 based on r316199) Clang 6.0.2 (https://a 
08-11 09:19:50.493 10715 10755 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "" 
08-11 09:19:50.494 10715 10755 I python  : [WARNING] [Deprecated  ] Python 2 Kivy support has been deprecated. The Kivy release after 1.11.0 will not support Python 2 anymore 
08-11 09:19:50.495 10715 10755 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last): 
08-11 09:19:50.495 10715 10755 I python  :    File "/home/laurent/Downloads/Files4apk/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 2, in <module> 
08-11 09:19:50.495 10715 10755 I python  :    File "/home/laurent/Downloads/Files4apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/digitable/kivy/__init__.py", line 139, in require 
08-11 09:19:50.496 10715 10755 I python  :  Exception: The version of Kivy installed on this system is too old. (You have 1.11.0, but the application requires 1.11.1) 
08-11 09:19:50.496 10715 10755 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

### Problem

1. In your buildozer.spec, you specified Kivy version 1.11.1 and Python 2 but in your
   Kivy app, (main.py), it has 1.11.0
2. Python 2 Kivy support has been deprecated. The Kivy release after 1.11.0 will not support Python 2 anymore

### Solution

1. Either remove the following in main.py or change it to `'1.11.1'` (i.e. same as buildozer.spec)

```
    import kivy
    kivy.require('1.11.0')
```

2. If you want to use Kivy version 1.11.1, you have to replace `python2` with `python3` for `requirements`

Comment: Thank you for helping me correcting this stupid mistake. What about the "osx.python_version" in the buildozer.spec. Should it be 2 or 3? So I changed everything to 1.11.0 and put python2 in requirements and I don't have this error. But still doesn't open. It crashes but not as fast as before. If you can have a look at the log.txt and logcat that would be awesome. Thank you. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dUIT0sFDofREzGG4l8lBLhK8VN4I5W8t   and https://drive.google.com/open?id=14f7XrudPKXNY0Ls_2UOelQE_brna-f7M

Comment: @Laurent Did you look at the logcat yourself to try to find the problem? Do you understand how ikolim found this first issue?

Comment: In this new logcat I don't see your app running at all.

Comment: I spent all day on it. I wasn't sure what I was looking for but basically tracking warnings, errors and exceptions. Since that last post, I tried quite a few things. I tried to correct issues (installed libraries that were giving me errors...). Apart from [Warning] Doing some hacky stuff to link properly ...", I think everything is clear. Now I have "[WARNING] [Deprecated  ] Python 2 Kivy support has been deprecated. The Kivy release after 1.11.0 will not support Python 2 anymore." Does that mean I have to downgrade Kivy since buildozer works with python2?

Comment: Sorry for the last logcat. This is my very last one: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Uqi0equHF5TYqHdLkQ01lrnbZE69NJeJ

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new with Kivy/buildozer. But I really have to deliver this app. I can't fail!    Just to make sure, it has to be 3 in osx.python_version (in the buildozer.spec), right? I'm just wondering if I should downgrade my script in python 2, or kivy, or something else?

Comment: @Laurent: The rerun of your Kivy app failed due to missing dependencies ['numpy', 'pytz', 'dateutil']. Solution: Add dependencies ['numpy', 'pytz', 'dateutil'] to requirements in buildozer.spec, `requirements = python2,kivy,pandas,numpy,pytz,dateutil`. Please check updated post for details.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I don't have these ImportError anymore. Great . But I have "TypeError: add_docstring() argument 2 must be str, not None" ... "Python for android ended". Plus I still have "Python 2 Kivy support has been deprecated. The Kivy release after 1.11.0 will not support Python 2 anymore". Even though I even put 1.0.6 on both the .spec and the main.py. Is the problem coming from the version of Kivy or is it Python? logcat : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Gty0Hqi2tgf272nspxPjR68b-Qg1W-Hi.      buildozer: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xt24DFTJ6Fj1nmJPMK5Yx6WjzehWBWfC

Comment: ... and the log.txt from buildozer in case: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pMwtjaBBqU8vvY4o9PvHR8dETjjReofK

Comment: Your app crashed because `TypeError: add_docstring() argument 2 must be str, not None`. Don't worry too much about the warning message because it is not causing your app to crash. If you really want to get rid of the warning then replace `python2` with `python3` for `requirements` and replace `osx.kivy_version = 1.0.6` with `osx.kivy_version = 1.11.1` in your `buildozer.spec`. But before you do that, make sure that your Kivy app is Python 3 compatible / ready.

Comment: I've downgraded kivy to 1.10.1 and changed versions in both the spec and main files. And I don't have the "Python 2Kivy support has beed deprecated...". I replaced python2 -> 3 in requirements and I have that now: "ImportError: C extension: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.test.digitable/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first... Python for android ended".  Any ideas?

Comment: SOLVED! The problem was the library Pandas. It was in front of my eyes... and here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/wpwnp7UjVks. In my requirements, I have python3 and I had to force version 1.11.1 to be used for kivy (kivy==1.11.1). Plus 1.11.1 also in my main.py. Thanks to all of you.   P.S. please add me just 1 reputation so I can have 15 and I can thank you all!